# How to show Bokeh Tabs when error "TypeError: object() takes no parameters" occurs?

Tags: python, bokeh

I have a list of tabs called "tabs_combined". I want to show the first element of this list : `show(tabs_combined[0])` on my dashboard.

Here is my code:

```
p1 = figure(plot_width=300, plot_height=300)
p1.circle([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 2, 4, 5], size=20, color="navy")

p2 = figure(plot_width=300, plot_height=300)
p2.line([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 2, 4, 5], line_width=3, color="navy")

tab1 = Panel(child=p1,title="circle")
tab2 = Panel(child=p2, title="line")

...

tabs_combined = [[tab1, tab2],[tab3, tab4]]

# Bokeh Tabs code
tabs_to_show = Tabs(tabs=tabs_combined[0])

final_layout = layout([
    [my_menu],
    [my_graph],
    [tabs_to_show]
    ])

show(final_layout)
```

The error produced is:

```
tabs_to_show = Tabs(tabs=tabs_combined[0])
TypeError: object() takes no parameters
```

From what I gather, Python thinks Tabs is a Python object, and not a Bokeh object? I've searched and `Tabs` isn't a Python keyword. Also, this code works in a jupyter notebook, but not when I run from `main.py` in my project.

Can someone advise me on where this issue is likely to be coming from? Thanks!

Comment: Whatever the source of the issue is, it's not in this snippet. If you can post a minimal, complete script that reproduces the issue (i.e. that someone who wants to help can take and just run) then the error will probably be quickly diagnosable.

Comment: Please show all imports you are using.